# Why isn't my microphone being detected by Settings|Sound|Input on Debian 10?

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio, microphone

I'm using Debian 10. When I go to Settings, Sound, Input, everything appears gray, as if there was no microphone.

[image: settings|sound|input]

However, the microphone is detected by `pavucontrol`.

[image: pavucontrol]

Still, the microphone is not working (it was until yesterday, with exactly the same situation on both programs). Actually, it only produces loud noise, as can be seen by the large blue bar in the second picture (right above "Advanced"). I think that solving the "undetected" situation on settings may be the first step in solving today's "not working".

Any ideas?

EDIT

I'm using a desktop, not a laptop/notebook.

It's not a USB microphone, it uses a common P10 connector (separated from the headphone connector).

`arecord -l` gives the same result, with the microphone connected or not:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC887-VD Alt Analog [ALC887-VD Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Output of `$ pacmd list-sources`:

```
2 source(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 1030
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: yes
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 6 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 40.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 7
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf220000 irq 128"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a170"
        device.product.name = "100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 6554 /  10% / -60.00 dB,   front-right: 6554 /  10% / -60.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 6554 /  10% / -60.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 4.07 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 40.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC887-VD Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC887-VD Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf220000 irq 128"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a170"
        device.product.name = "100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC887-VD"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0887,1849d887,00100302"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                
    active port: <analog-input-front-mic>
```

Results of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec#*`:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card*/codec#*
Codec: Realtek ALC887-VD
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0887
Subsystem Id: 0x1849d887
Revision Id: 0x100302
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x5f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=2, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=0
  IO[0]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[1]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Front Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC887-VD Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x31 0x31]
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x31 0x31]
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x04 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Surround Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x05 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Center Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="LFE Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=2, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x06 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x611: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x07 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x08 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC887-VD Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x10, nsteps=0x2e, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x10 0x10]
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x23
Node 0x09 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=1, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=1, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC887-VD Alt Analog", type="Audio", device=2
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x10, nsteps=0x2e, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0xa6 0xa6]
  Converter: stream=2, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x22
Node 0x0a [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100711: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x1f
Node 0x0b [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Mic Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=1, ofs=0
  Control: name="Mic Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=1, ofs=0
  Control: name="Rear Mic Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Rear Mic Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x9f 0x9f] [0x13 0x13] [0x9f 0x9f] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 10
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1c 0x1d 0x14 0x15 0x16 0x17
Node 0x0c [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 2
     0x02 0x0b
Node 0x0d [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 2
     0x03 0x0b
Node 0x0e [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 2
     0x04 0x0b
Node 0x0f [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 2
     0x05 0x0b
Node 0x10 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x611: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x11 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400781: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x40000000: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x10
Node 0x12 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400401: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x13 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x14 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Front Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0001003e: IN OUT HP EAPD Detect Trigger
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x01014020: [Jack] Line Out at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Green
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=02, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x0c
Node 0x15 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00000036: IN OUT Detect Trigger
  Pin Default 0x90170110: [Fixed] Speaker at Int N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x0d
Node 0x16 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x00000036: IN OUT Detect Trigger
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x0e
Node 0x17 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x00000036: IN OUT Detect Trigger
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x0f
Node 0x18 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Center Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="LFE Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=2, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Rear Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x00003736: IN OUT Detect Trigger
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x01a19040: [Jack] Mic at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Pink
    DefAssociation = 0x4, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x21: IN VREF_50
  Unsolicited: tag=04, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 5
     0x0c* 0x0d 0x0e 0x0f 0x26
Node 0x19 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000373e: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x02a19050: [Jack] Mic at Ext Front
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Pink
    DefAssociation = 0x5, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=03, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 5
     0x0c* 0x0d 0x0e 0x0f 0x26
Node 0x1a [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Surround Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x00003736: IN OUT Detect Trigger
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x0181304f: [Jack] Line In at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Blue
    DefAssociation = 0x4, Sequence = 0xf
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=05, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 5
     0x0c* 0x0d 0x0e 0x0f 0x26
Node 0x1b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0001373e: IN OUT HP EAPD Detect Trigger
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x02214030: [Jack] HP Out at Ext Front
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Green
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0xc0: OUT HP VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 5
     0x0c 0x0d 0x0e 0x0f 0x26*
Node 0x1c [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400481: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000024: IN Detect
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400400: Mono
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x4026c629: [N/A] HP Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Digital, Color = UNKNOWN
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x9
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1e [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400781: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x06
Node 0x1f [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400681: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x20 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00040: Mono
  Processing caps: benign=0, ncoeff=24
Node 0x21 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x22 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 12
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1c 0x1d 0x14 0x15 0x16 0x17 0x0b 0x12
Node 0x23 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 11
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1c 0x1d 0x14 0x15 0x16 0x17 0x0b
Node 0x24 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x25 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x31 0x31]
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x26 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 2
     0x25 0x0b
Codec: Nvidia GPU 60 HDMI/DP
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x10de0060
Subsystem Id: 0x14583667
Revision Id: 0x100100
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x0]:
    bits [0x0]:
    formats [0x0]:
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=0, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=0, wake=0
Node 0x04 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x407381: 8-Channels Digital CP
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Connection: 4
     0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b
Node 0x05 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x407381: 8-Channels Digital CP
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=1, device=0
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=02, enabled=1
  Connection: 4
     0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b
Node 0x06 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x407381: 8-Channels Digital CP
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=2, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=2, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=2, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=2, device=0
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=03, enabled=1
  Connection: 4
     0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b
Node 0x07 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x407381: 8-Channels Digital CP
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=3, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=3, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=3, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=3, device=0
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=04, enabled=1
  Connection: 4
     0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b
Node 0x08 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x62b1: 8-Channels Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
Node 0x09 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x62b1: 8-Channels Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
Node 0x0a [Audio Output] wcaps 0x62b1: 8-Channels Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
Node 0x0b [Audio Output] wcaps 0x62b1: 8-Channels Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0## Heading ##
```

EDIT 2

The "ghost in the machine" is making fun on me.

[image: ghost]

The only component of `alsamixer` that made a difference on the recording volume at Audacity was "Capture", the one at highest level below.

[image: alsamixer]

Comment: "It works with my smartphone" Does that mean it's a USB microphone? If yes, please update the question with this and the following info: check with `lsusb` if the hardware is detected, check with `arecord -l` if it's detected by ALSA. This should give an indication at what level something goes wrong.

Comment: @dirkt Sorry, it was probably the smartphone that recorded my voice, not the microphone. I deleted that part and added more information (except the lsusb, since it's not a USB device). Thank you.

Comment: Possibly [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352379/headphone-not-working-linux-mint-18/486722) helps, even though it's for headphone. It also shows how you can debug the codec pin detection.

Comment: @dirkt Hi! I've read it all, but couldn't find anything that help me. I'm pasting the last results on pastebin, link on the question.

Comment: The trick to debug pin detection is to have one codec dump without the mic plugged in, and one with the mic plugged in. Then you can see if there's a difference. "Last results" aren't going to help.

Comment: @dirkt Well, both `amixer -c0 contents` and `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec#*` give exactly the same results with or without the mic plugged in. I already knew that my Debian cannot detect the plug, as is visible in the second image.

Comment: That's a very informative question. Thanks for all the detection commands.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

> Both `amixer -c0` contents and `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec#*` give exactly the same results with or without the mic plugged in.

That means your codec cannot detect that the mic is plugged in, for whatever reasons.

In particular it rules out that the BIOS assigns wrong values to the pin complexes (a not unusual bug, in particular with laptops), and that ALSA is just not picking up the codec changes (also happens).

So either the hardware is broken (then there's no way to get it to work), or you may be able to set up the correct configuration to get at the mic manually. So solving the "undetected situation" is not going to help.

If you change the volume settings, do they influence the load noise in any way? Which settings do influence it, which don't?

**Edit**

Ok, so mapping the topology from the codec I arrive at

```
N = Node  P = Pin  M = Mixer  I = Audio In  O = Audio Out  S = Selector
V = Vendor

O02 "Front"
O03 "Speaker"
O04 "Surround"
O05 "Center"
O06 "Digital"
V07
I08 <- N23  Main
I09 <- N22  Alt
I0a <- P1f  Digital
M0b <- P18 P19 P1a P1b P1c P1d P14 P15 P16 P17  
M0c <- O02 M0b                  "Loopback 1"
M0d <- O03 M0b                  "Loopback 2"
M0e <- O04 M0b                  "Loopback 3"
M0f <- O05 M0b                  "Loopback 4"
O10 "Digital"
P11 Line out
P12                             ??      Speaker Ext Rear
V13
P14 <- M0c                      OUT     Line Out Ext Rear
P15 <- M0d                      OUT     Speaker Int
P16 <- M0e                      IN      Speaker Ext Rear  Black
P17 <- M0f                      IN      Speaker Ext Rear  Black
P18 <- M0c M0d M0e M0f N26      IN      Mic Ext Rear
P19 <- M0c M0d M0e M0f N26      IN      Mic Ext Front
P1a <- M0c M0d M0e M0f N26      IN      Line In Ext Rear
P1b <- M0c M0d M0e M0f N26      OUT     HP Out
P1c                             IN
P1d                             IN
P1e <- O06                      OUT DIG
P1f                             IN
V20
V21
M22 <- P18 P19 P1a P1b P1c P1d P14 P15 P16 P17 M9b P12          Alt
M23 <- P18 P19 P1a P1b P1c P1d P14 P15 P16 P17 M9b              Main
V24
O25
M26 <- O25 M0b
```

This means P16 and P17 are labelled wrong by the BIOS (should be OUT), and are probably unconnected. M22 and M23 are the recording mixers for the two inputs, and M0b is the loopback mixer.

Looking at the ALSA labels, it seems like ALSA gets confused by the topology, and assigns the labels wrongly.

So what you hear is just noise picked up from somewhere in the codec, as ALSA is making the wrong connections when recording.

1) Test the detection again by making a codec dump without the MIC plugged in, plugging it in, and making a second codec dump. Compare both dumps with `diff`. You *should* see a difference in Node P18 or P19. A very small difference.

2) You can try `hdajackretask` to correct P16 and P17, and see if that stops confusing ALSA.

3) If you understand how the codec works, you can use `hda-verb` from the `alsa-tools` package to manually correct wrong assignments ALSA makes during recording, and see if you get it correct that way.

4) File a bug report with the ALSA developers (google), and include enough codec dumps to show the wrong assignments.

Comment: Yes, on `pavucontrol`, if I slide the volume from Base towards the 100% (0dB), the blue bar below grows to the right. It also changes the noise volume that Audacity records.

Comment: `pavucontrol` isn't going to help, because it controls various mixer settings. Try `alsamixer` (and **all** controls you can change). In particular we need the path towards the source, to see where the noise is coming from.

Comment: Let me get this straight: `solving the "undetected situation" is not going to help` means that there's no microphone enabled in the first picture because my system cannot detect the microphone plug being inserted? But I remember seeing it working, months ago. I was using Debian 9 back then (now I'm on 10).

Comment: Looks like there's a ghost in the machine. Now both "Line In" and "Rear Microphone" appeared on Settings (but not the "Front Microphone", which is the one I just plugged in again). Take a look at the new picture.

Comment: And now sliding the volume on pavucontrol does NOT change the blue bar below anymore. This %&$@# is going to make me crazy!

Comment: Added to the question what I've found with alsamixer.

Comment: So, nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sometimes Pulse Audio configuration gets corrupted leading to not detecting input devices like microphones.

To reset the Pulse Audio config, do the following:

1. Delete the following durectory: `~/.config/pulse`.
2. Restart Pulse Audio: `pulseaudio -k ; pulseaudio -D`